# Reduce Auto-Save Trigger time on MS CRM

Tags: sql, crm, autosave

I am fairly new to MS CRM and I'm supposed to reduce the atuo-save trigger time from 30 seconds to 15. I found instructions online but I don't know enough about the system to know how to implement them. The instructions are as follows:

> You will have to modify the “AutoSaveInterval” value in the
>   “DeploymentProperties” table in the “MSCRM_CONFIG” SQL Server
>   database. The value is in second(s) unit.
>
> Retrieving Auto-save feature interval trigger time
>
> ```
> 1 SELECT IntColumn FROM DeploymentProperties 
>
> 2 WHERE ColumnName = 'AutoSaveInterval'
> ```
>
> Modifying Auto-save feature interval trigger time
>
> ```
> 1 UPDATE DeploymentProperties
>
> 2 SET IntColumn = 100
>
> 3 WHERE ColumnName = 'AutoSaveInterval'
> ```

These are the only instructions I've found online. They're repeated across the internet.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. 
Thank you!

Comment: What part are you having trouble with?

Comment: FYI for all, this is only an (unsupported) option for on-premise. For online, there's no option.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the auto-save interval in On-Premise deployments using the Update statement below that will work in SQL Server Management Studio even if you have the database context set to some database other than the MSCRM_CONFIG database.  ** Note that this is unsupported as it's not documented in the official Microsoft CRM documentation. **

One other note regarding this is that I didn't see this take effect until running an IIS Reset after running the SQL update statement, so have added that as a step as I have tested and verified that this works.  Also note that this will also increase the load on your Microsoft CRM Server and Microsoft SQL Server since you've effectively told the CRM platform that you want to save records twice as frequently if any changes are detected, so if you see negative performance impact from this, it would be good to switch back to the CRM default setting.

1. Run the Update Statement below on the SQL Server containing the Microsoft CRM databases (the select statement allows you to see the existing setting).
2. Run an IISReset on the Microsoft Dynamics CRM Server for the change above to take effect (this should ideally be done after regular business hours).

   SELECT IntColumn from MSCRM_CONFIG.dbo.DeploymentProperties
   WHERE ColumnName = 'AutoSaveInterval'

   **--Default = 30 (in seconds)
   UPDATE MSCRM_CONFIG.dbo.DeploymentProperties
   SET IntColumn = 15
   WHERE ColumnName = 'AutoSaveInterval'**

[Manage Auto-Save](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn531073.aspx)
is a good article on how to manage auto-save and shows the steps for disabling it

> "(Settings - Administration - System Settings - Pick No for the option, "Enable auto-save for all forms").  Note that you can also disable it for a specific entity by adding code to the OnSave event for an entity in the CRM Customizations and to add the following function, preventAutoSave to the onSave event web resource, making sure to mark the option, "Pass execution context as the first parameter" to this function. (the article has full details on those steps).

```
function preventAutoSave(econtext) {
    var eventArgs = econtext.getEventArgs();
    if (eventArgs.getSaveMode() == 70 || eventArgs.getSaveMode() == 2) {
        eventArgs.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there is no supported way of reducing the auto-save interval; it is possible to disable it altogether, but not reduce. The suggested solution you found is an unsupported change and would only be applicable to On-Premises deployments.

I haven't tried the approach myself, but you would need to run the update statement on the CRM configuration database - `MSCRM_CONFIG` and it would likely affect all organizations in the deployment.